# Properties of Average Multinomial Likelihood

Tags: likelihood, multinomial-distribution, kullback-leibler

I am trying to understand the Kullback-Leibler Information:

[image]

I read in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2000v1.pdf the following:

*Ideally, we want the probability to be invariant to the number of measurements - this
is given by the average likelihood $\overline{L} = L^{1/n}$, a number between 0 and 1. Matching intuition, as we perform more
measurements, if $c_i/n \rightarrow  q_i$
, then the average likelihood would be perfect, or $\overline{L} \rightarrow 1$. Conversely, as $c_i/n $
diverges
from the model $q_i$
, the average likelihood $\overline{L}$ decreases, approaching zero.*

1) This is actually not intuitive for me, why $\overline{L}$ goes to 0 as the models diverge, and 1 as the models converge. Yes, I understand that the likelihood is smaller for a model diverging from reality, than a model better representing reality. But how this average log likelihood goes to 0 or 1, I cannot see.

*We now begin the derivation by remembering that independent observations constituting a histogram are multiplied
together to recover the joint probability of all measurements. Thus, an invariant likelihood across histogram counts is
the geometric mean of the multinomial likelihood $L(c|q)^{1/n}$. We term this quantity the average multinomial likelihood,
or average likelihood for short. We start by defining the average log-likelihood as $\overline{L}=L(c|q)^{1/n}$*

2) Why are we interested in an invariant likelihood when deriving the KL divergence?